# Nativescript Vue: Matching small screen design to large screen?

Tags: nativescript, nativescript-vue

I built an app and in the xcode simulator, it looks as it should on the iPhone 11 but on the iPhone SE, all the content doesn't fit.  I can resolve this by wrapping everything in a `ScrollView` so that I can scroll down on small screens but is this the correct approach?
Or should I have a separate stylesheet directed towards small screens like iPhone SE and have all the content fit on screen like iPhone 11?

Comment: Are you using flexbox? It would be best to share some code so that we can help from that point.

Comment: @davidkihara just added code.  I am using StackLayout as my primary container

Comment: Use Grids. You can set percentages using the GridUnitType.Star class. If you setup your RowDefintions and ColumnDefinitions correctly, your page will resize on all device screen sizes and even on landscape. Check this link for more information https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/122805/how-to-create-a-responsive-layout-to-run-in-all-device-with-xamarin-forms-net-standard

Comment: Whether or not to use a ScrollView depends on what you like. If you want your content to fit all the time irrespective of available space, then you should use GridLayout If you want user to view all the content in good shape & size, then you will use ScrollView.